# Make server only respond when accessed via specific subdomain

Tags: dns, proxy, home-networking, reverse-proxy, subdomain

I have searched and searched the internet for this problem for hours and I can't seem to find a solution or if it's even possible what I'm trying.

**I am behind double-NAT which hasn't been a problem so far.**

My domain is **mydomain.com** and its associated IP is dynamic. I host various different kinds of servers (games, web, voice, chat). 
The domain registrar allows me to have 10 subdomains for my domain which all get updated with the same IP.

I would love to use those subdomains to logically seperate the services. For example use game.mydomain.com for all my game servers, voice.mydomain.com for VoIP services, chat.mydomain.com for my chat service.

Currently I can get on my Minecraft-Server with all subdomains since they all resolve to the same IP which is expected behaviour.

**Now to my question:** *Is there a way to make Minecraft only respond when the address used to connect is "game.mydomain.com?* Same applies to the other services as well.

I've looked into reverse proxies but read that they redirect based on protocol in the headers and thus are generally only used for HTTP/HTTPS.

Thank you for taking time to respond.

PS: I know that hosting services in such a scenario (dynamic IP) is not the good-practices way but nobody I don't know is accessing the services and they don't mind the short disconnects when the IP changes.

Answer (score 1):

This works with HTTP because your browser explicitly tells the server the address that was used to request the resource, in the `Host` header.

Of course it’s possible for other protocols to support a similar mechanism. However, *in general*, network protocols don’t. One notable exception is TLS with SNI. The client still has to support it explicitly.

There is no way to do this.

You can still have various subdomains though, just to make things look nice.

Answer (score 1):

On the **connection** level, the domain name used is simply not transmitted - it is based only on the resolved IP addresses, not the name used to resolve them. This implies, that it is simply impossible for a server to respond to only one domain name.

On the **protocol** level, things are different: Some protocols (HTTP[S] being the canonical example) the requested name is transmitted, giving the server a possibility to switch between different services. On other protocols (e.g. FTP or SMTP) the requested name is not part of the protocol.

AFAIK Minecraft does not use the name inside the protocol, so the construction you want to have is not permitted by the composition of the network.

Answer (score 0):

> I've looked into reverse proxies but read that they redirect based on protocol in the headers and thus are generally only used for HTTP/HTTPS.

But that's exactly the problem here. If your protocol doesn't send the domain name in its headers, then your server has no way to distinguish the 'domain' requests either!

So no, this is not possible unless you get a second IP address (or unless Minecraft actually starts sending the domain name).

Answer (score 0):

As the connection to your devices is by IP address, and since only some of the
protocols conserve the original domain name, you could perhaps attack the problem
using ports.

Your different servers use different ports for communicating, so you need to map
the different sub-domains to their different ports.
The mapping would look like "game.mydomain.com:port1 => IP:port2".
The IP would always be the same, but not the port.
This would be augmented by port-forwarding on your router for these ports,
directing the connection to the right server.

You would have a mapping for each type of server. You could also have
a mapping for wrong connections, to avoid for example a game accessing
the wrong game server and causing it to crash.

If your ISP does not offer such an option, some Dynamic DNS services give
it, some for free, some paid.

Comment: I do not fully understand that.
How and where is this mapping done? Do you mean port-forwarding?
pfSense allows port-forwarding with source and destination IP adresses not domain names. I only have 1 IP shared with all subdomains.

Comment: This is done by the DNS/DynDNS provider when handling your (sub)domain address. See for example how this is done with Namecheap [How to redirect (sub)domain to a certain IP address along with a port](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9678/2237/how-to-redirect-subdomain-to-a-certain-ip-address-along-with-a-port).

Comment: "5) It is not a gaming, FTP, remote desktop or radio broadcast service. It is not possible to redirect a domain to an IP address of the server that is not running on port 80 by default using this method. In such case, an SRV record should be created in addition to an A record. "
I have looked into SRV records as well. However I am still trying to wrap my head around this. I can't figure out why this would prevent the server from being acces with mydomain.com instead of game.mydomain.com since both resolve to the same IP.

Comment: With such a service, both resolve to the same IP but not to the same port. Example: Game server runs on local IP `192.168.010` port `123`. The user asks address `game.mydomain.com:port1`. The DNS/DynDNS server redirects it to `ExternalIP:port2`. This arrives to the router (which is on ExternalIP) on `port2`, so then router redirects the connection to `192.168.010` port `123`. The simplest might be to ask the Support of the DNS/DynDNS server what exactly to do.

Comment: Thank you. I have contacted them already a few minutes back and I am hoping for a response. It is also easier to do this in my native language.